# Only hair rendering, why?

Tags: rendering, texturing, particles, hair

my model, which has texture painting and a skin colour is not showing up on render. Only the hair shows on render. I've tried clearing the restricted render, which I didn't set up anyway, all sorts, but only the hair shows. The hair is particles, I was following a tutorial to try this out and had the hair attached to a vertex group only. When it didn't render the body, I tried duplicating the scalp to another layer and having no particles on the main figure (though it still has wispy hair attached there, no idea why) Can anyone help? I am using cycles render and 2.79. Picture is a bit rubbish, but I'm only learning[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure **Emitter** is checked under **Render** at the **Particles** panel.

[image: Emitter location at Particles panel]

Comment: No problem, and welcome to Stack Exchange! Don't forget to mark the question as answered. :)